# Python csv.writer without filehandler

Tags: python, csv

csv.writer requires me to feed in a real csv file. is there a way I can feed it a string or a list to write to instead of an actual file? I want to return the csv for another function without writing a file.

```
hold = [some_list]
blank = []
   w = csv.writer(blank, delimiter=',')
   w.writerows(hold)
   return w

Traceback (most recent call last):
    w = csv.writer(blank, delimiter=',')
    TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) object is suitable for this:

```
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> w = csv.writer(f)
>>> w.writerow(['hello', 'world'])
13
>>> f.getvalue()
'hello,world\r\n'
```

Comment: I am using python 2 so io.BytesIO worked for me but this led me there. Thank you!